# C++. Как объявить статический объект с builder setter'ами?

Tags: c++, ооп

Например в моем коде нужно объявить стандартные атрибуты автомобилей, чтобы потом использовать уже готовые заготовки

```
static Car* civicd15b = new Car('A',1,"Honda Civic D15B VTEK")->SetFriction(-0.2)->SetWeight(1400)->SetMax_speed(220);
```

Компилятор ругается на `expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘->’ token`. Что делать и где объявлять объекты эти?

Comment: Сделать нормальный конструктор никак?

Comment: @gbg а если у меня много переменных, конструктор с 30 аргументами - моветон

Comment: на это дело можно применить шаблонную магию - написать парсер аргументов во время компиляции, и задавать их в одной строке, хоть JSON - ом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ларчик открывается просто - надо добавить скобки вокруг вызова `new`:

```
static Car* civicd15b = ( new Car('A',1,"Honda Civic D15B VTEK") )\
->SetFriction(-0.2)->SetWeight(1400)->SetMax_speed(220);
```

Тогда у вас будет сначала конструктор, а потом вся прочая компания.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предпочел использовать отдельную функцию, возвращающую сконструированный необходимым образом объект:

```
const Car& Сivicd15b() {
    static Car ret = Car('A',1,"Honda Civic D15B VTEK");
    ret.SetFriction(-0.2);
    ret.SetWeight(1400);
    ret.SetMax_speed(220);
    return ret;
}
```

И инициализировать статический объект так:

```
static const Car& civicd15b = Сivicd15b();
```

При этом, вероятно, при использовании C++Builder и компилятора без поддержки `c++11` на строку со `static Car ret` будет выдано предупреждение о необходимости синхронизировать доступ к `static` переменной в многопоточном окружении. В таком случае, можно отказаться от `static` внутри функции и возвращать уже не по ссылке, а по значению (и даже без `const`). Правда, это может привести к дополнительному копированию `Car`.